# Viso2 mono_odometer error

Tags: navigation, odometry, visual-odometry, viso2, libviso2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am trying to use the viso2 package in order to obtain the monocular visual odometry using a Firefly mv camera. The camera works fine and I am able to view the images. However, when I run the command:

rosrun viso2_ros mono_odometer image:=/camera/image_raw

I get the following warnings and error:

---

[WARN] [1358388437.751639814]: parameter 'camera_height' is required but not set.
Using default: 1.000000

[WARN] [1358388437.752287274]: parameter 'camera_pitch' is required but not set.
Using default: 0.000000

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

---

Any idea what is causing this segmentation fault?

Thanks and best regards,

Khalid

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52522/viso2-mono_odometer-error/) by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 735 on 2013-01-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-01-16**:
I am not sure why it is not showing the warnings, I get a couple of warnings regarding setting the camera height and camera pitch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that you do not use rectified images. Please [calibrate your camera](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_calibration/Tutorials/MonocularCalibration) and make sure the camera driver pubishes the accurate [CameraInfo](http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_pipeline/CameraInfo) messages. Run [image_proc](http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_proc) in the camera's namespace to generate rectified images from your raw input.
Then let mono_odometer subscribe to `<your camera>/image_rect`. If you still have problems, please modify your question to include the full console output of `mono_odometer`.

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2013-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-01-18**:
Thanks Stephan for your reply, I will try that and update the question.

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-01-20**:
Hi Stephans, I calibrated the camera, and subscribed to image_raw and not image_rect (which does not publish anything) and now it works. I am not sure if what i did is correct? camra_info seems to be publishing the calibrated camera information. However, I cannot find the rectified image.

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2013-01-20**:
You have to run image_ proc to generate rectified images.

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-01-20**:
Thanks for your response, I  am running the image_proc node, but I have just realized that I forgot to add the remapping from image_rect to camera_image_rect in my launch file. I will try this later and let you know if it works.

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-01-21**:
Ok I realized I was not running the image_proc node in the proper way. Now it works, Thanks alot for your help. I have another question about VISO2 that I will post in a new thread so it can help others.

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2013-01-21**:
If your issue is resolved, please mark the answer as correct so that it does not show up as "unanswered" any more.

**Comment by [Dava2788](https://answers.ros.org/users/3554/dava2788/) on 2013-10-01**:
Hi can any of you give an example of the launch file to run Viso2. Because i'm trying to developed that lauch file and i can't.  My problem is I'm not able to generated rectified images. I just put my problem in this link:*http://answers.ros.org/question/84611/what-things-do-i-need-to-make-a-rectification-image-in-image-proc*
I will appreciate any respond . Thank you